# Is there a way to get a list of intalled jenkins plugins with vulnerabilities?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

As part of a security project, I am looking to write an automation that ensures that there are no active warnings/vulnerabilities published against a plugin that is installed in Jenkins. Is there a way to get a list of vulnerabilities issued by jenkins against the plugins installed?
I tried to figure out how the 'Manage Jenkins' page is displaying plugin warnings and found that it is running a POST against "/administrativeMonitor/jenkins.security.UpdateSiteWarningsMonitor/forward". Can we make use of this somehow?

Comment: Not sure why this is vote to close/downvote as it seems like a legitimate programming question, validated by concise answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use groovy: [getActivePluginWarningsByPlugin](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/security/UpdateSiteWarningsMonitor.html#getActivePluginWarningsByPlugin--).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Jenkins plugin manager should solve your problem with just a simple command

```
java -jar jenkins-plugin-manager-*.jar --war /your/path/to/jenkins.war --plugins delivery-pipeline-plugin:1.3.2 deployit-plugin --view-security-warnings
```

Here **--view-security-warnings** does the magic & gives list of plugins with warnings/vulnerabilites.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool

Comment: @Darkc0de3 does this resolves  your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @ian-w s answer, you can run this in the Jenkins groovy console:

```
import jenkins.security.*
ExtensionList.lookupSingleton(UpdateSiteWarningsMonitor.class).getActivePluginWarningsByPlugin().each { key, value ->
   println "$key.shortName: ${value.collect{ it.message }.join('; ')}"
}
return ""
```